# auto column insertion during data importing in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

- I have five column in `.csv` file and i have to import it in `MySQL table`.
- But i also required date on which i import file in database.

So i mean six column in table with today date.

- I have tried with use `time stamp` as `datatype` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in `default`.

But it occurs query:-  `Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.`

Please guide me.

Screen Shot:-
[image]

Csv File:-
[image]

Comment: Even if it is a timestamp, you need to add an empty value in your insert. The columns of the table and the number of column in your insert query should match.

Comment: actually i not use mysql query but i simply import data using `import` menu in Wampserver.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the schema for the table. And the code used to do the import

Comment: There is no Import menu in WAMPServer!! Do you mean you are using the IMPORT menu in `phpMyAdmin` which is equivalent to a table restore

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes

Comment: post the table structure and csv columns..that ll help us to understand your problem more

Comment: [`ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: @SmitSaraiya Try this stackoverflow solution [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43223126/1676023)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the number of column in your csv and table is not same. If you want to set default value of any column you have to keep this value empty but you have to mention this column. For example: if you want to insert 3 columns having a default value for 1 column named 'created' your csv file should look like this:

[image]

Please remove first row which describes your table structure. I mean do not  use the following instead of the above:
[image]

And finally run the following sql if current timestamp is not set:

```
UPDATE `table` SET edate = current_timestamp;
```

Here put your table name it 'table' phrase.

Comment: It show error `#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'edate' at row 1`

Comment: please share your sample csv data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DEFAULT constraints to set the timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE
 MODIFY edate datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

ALTER TABLE
 MODIFY edate datetime DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: i think this will help you